# How to set Kotlin source encoding in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, character-encoding, kotlin

When building Java or Groovy using Gradle, it's possible to define source encoding like this:

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileGroovy {
    groovyOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

compileTestGroovy {
    groovyOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

However, similar approach with Kotlin doesn't work:

```
compileKotlin {        
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = '1.8'
    kotlinOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

It fails with the error:

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'backend'.
> No such property: encoding for class: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.dsl.KotlinJvmOptionsImpl
```

I actually can't find any info about Kotlin compiler's encoding at all. Does it mean that there is no such option? What charset does it use then, UTF-8, system default (I hope not)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's always UTF-8, although I can't find it documented.

Comment: `Does it mean that there is no such option?` - After checking there source code I can tell you: No. There is no such option. You can check the DSL for the plugin [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/gradle/dsl). Specially the `KotlinJvmOptions*` are interested for you for what is available and whats not. Unfortunately I can't say you which default encoding they use...

Comment: I found this statement `All Kotlin source files use the UTF-8 character encoding` at https://medium.com/@napperley/unofficial-kotlin-style-guide-a44cb899a84f. But it seems to be best practices. I guess that if UTF-8 works and other encodings don't and there is no way to specify the actual encoding, you are stuck to UTF-8.

Comment: @Natix what is your gradle wrapper version?

Comment: @JTeam Depends, I usually try to use the latest Gradle available. Does it matter?

Answer (score 17):

Kotlin source files are always UTF-8 by design. There is no way to specify any other encoding.